# Is this sentence correct 今天你想我了没 ？

Tags: phrase-meaning

I saw some people wrote the following sentence.

```
今天你想我了没 ？
```

I thought the question would be: Today, do you miss me or not?
I am just a very beginner. But for the same meaning I would ask as following.

```
你今天想不想我吗？
```

So, is `今天你想我了没?` a correct sentence/question? How about my question, is it correct or not?

Comment: If you want to say "miss" in the typically romantic sense, it is 想念, as in 我很想念你, (I miss you very much) Here's a nice song about 想, called 亲爱的你在想我吗 -- https://youtu.be/YaK_Y07dqtQ

Answer (score 1):

今天你想我了没？ Did you miss me today? or have you miss me today? "or not" is unnecessary. This sentence is quite poetic.

你今天想不想我吗？ This is not a good sentence, "想不想" means "do you want to", so it does not fit the question well. Let's say "你今天想我了吗?" or "你今天想我不?". But as a general question without a specific date, you can ask "你想不想我?" or simply "你想我吗？"

Comment: So, "想不想" means "do you want it or not".

Comment: Yes. "想不想去吃飯?", "想不想回家?" - "Do you want to eat?", "Do you want to go home?"

Comment: Why do you omit the translation of "不想" = "or not?"

Comment: It is just unnecessary - "do you miss me or not?" = "do you miss me?" The latter is shorter yet more sophisticated. The former sounds like the whining from a teenager :)

Comment: I see. I just want learn to translate things literally.

Comment: "你今天想我不?" is your correct sentence. How about "你今天不想我?" is it correct?

Comment: I think a better translator is one that can catch the message of a sentence, then find the equivalent in his/her own language rather than translate word by word that may end up in a way nobody speaks. Your case is not that critical, but keep in mind that a brief but to the point sentence is always preferred over a sentence with too many descriptive words that make it vague to the readers/listeners,

Comment: "你今天不想我嗎?", 嗎 can't be eliminated in this case. As well in "今天想我了嗎?"

Comment: is "你今天想我没?" without "了" also correct?

Comment: Yes, for casual talks. The sentence is more formal/complete with "了".

Answer (score 1):

今天你想我了没 ？ is correct. Your sentence works without 吗, like 你今天想不想我？.

verb+了没 is kinda pattern we can use most of time. E.g. 说了没, 发了没, 想了没, etc. 了 can be omitted like 说没, 发没, 想没.

Comment: How do people know that 你今天想不想我？means "Today, do you miss me or not? and not "Today, do you want me or not?"

Comment: @OConnor Normally, it means do you miss me or not. "do you want me or not" would normally be 你今天想不想要我？, which sounds pretty flirtatious.

Comment: is 今天你想我没? without 了 also correct?

Comment: @OConnor Yeah, it's fine.